# How can I create a cert file?

Tags: c#, makecert

This is my first question in this site.

I wann to create a .cer file from scratch. I know I can use makecert. But I want to create it from my C#. I'm already doing it using `Process.Start` to start makecert. is there anyother way to do that?
I'm using .NET 4.5 in my C# code.

With thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bouncy castle library, that is an open source project originally written in Java and ported to C#.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/